# Connecting to Pepper via choregraphe / python scripts when Pepper is not connected to the same network

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

Is it possible to connect to a Pepper robot via choregraphe/python scripts when Pepper is not at the same network as I am?

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark as answer

Comment: I will, just can not test it yet. I am waiting for a robot to come.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it is a lot of trouble. Just get a dedicated wifi hotspot for your robot.

Say you are on network A and pepper is on network B.
You will need a machine on network B which you can use as tunnel endpoint.
https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html